# Pearson Correlation of same values

Tags: correlation, python, pearson-r, pandas

I got this problem while computing the pearson correlation of two datasets where one set consists of the same value. For example this pandas DataFrame:

```
tdf = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]], columns=["a", "b"])
tdf.corr()
```

As a results from pandas correlation function I just geht 'NaN' values. I guess it is because the nominator and denominator from pearson formula are zero. But shouldn't the correlation value should be '1'? Do I missunderstand something?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. You already gave the answer, the standard deviation is zero. Why should there be a correlation of 1? Try instead $(1,2,3)$ for both variables.

Comment: Think of this graphically or geometrically. You have three points that will plot at the same position. The algebra says that they all follow $b = 2a$ (in your notation) but the geometry does not define a unique straight-line summary. (I recommend thinking of these as two variables, not two datasets.)

Answer (score 3):

Please see the formula below:

[image]

The standard deviations in the denominator are each zero, so you end up dividing by 0, which gives you the NaN value for Corr(A,B).